# How to deploy project laravel with subfolder/domain

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, deployment

I want to ask about deploying laravel to apache server, this is the link when it is on local https://intranet.xxx.net.id/beranda-hc, now after deploying it becomes https://intranet.xxx.net.id/portal -hc / homepage-hc file and it becomes inaccessible or your routing problem, are there any suggestions when deploying the application to the server? This I move the public file to the root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create .htaccess file and paste this code and make sure you have `server.php` file on your root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: put in root or in public folder?

Comment: put .htaccess in root